# Can 'mainEntityOfPage' point to another page?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

I have two pages:

1. `page1.html`:

   ```
   WEBPAGE->MainEntity->ARTICLE  {
       inside ARTICLE I have PRODUCT with short description 
   }
   ```
2. `page2.html`:

   ```
   WEBPAGE->MainEntity->PRODUCT {
       "Full description of PRODUCT"
   }
   ```

**Can I declare `mainEntityOfPage` on `page1.html` which points to `page2.html`?**

For example:

```html
<article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <meta itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="Article page" itemscope itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="http://example.com/page1.html"/>    
    <div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <h2 itemprop="name"><a href="http://example.com/page2.html" itemprop="mainEntityOfPage">Product name</a></h2>
        <p itemprop="description">Product short description</p>
    </div>    
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as [its definition](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) says "Indicates a page […]".

If it were intended only for the current page, there would have been no point in expecting a [*URL*](http://schema.org/URL) as value, as a [*Boolean*](http://schema.org/Boolean) value would have sufficed.

---

In your example, it’s probably not necessary to define [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) *and* [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) for the `Article` (assuming that the markup is on the page `http://example.com/page1.html`), because these properties are defined to be inverse anyway. But it doesn’t harm either (and it could even help in cases where a consumer only supports one of these, without caring about the fact that they are defined to be inverse).

If the `Article` is about the `Product`, you may want to use the [`about` property](http://schema.org/about). Currently these two items are not related to each other in any way.

And you might want to use the [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) in addition to the `mainEntityOfPage` property for the `Product` (`itemprop="mainEntityOfPage url"`).

Comment: **unor**
I can't comment tour answer (rep<50), but want to do few remarks. 1. I use **mainEntity** and **mainEntityOfPage** and **MainContentOFPage** (in main tag) to be sure. 2. According **about** property i'm not sure, because: - My **Article** describes too many aspects related to **Product**
- Inside **Article** page i can have up to 6 **Product** (maybe i must use **SomeProducts** and my **about** must be as property of **SomeProducts**) 3. Thanks for **url** advice. When i look in validator **mainEntityOfPage** and **url** points to the same page *page2.html*, but to be sure - I'll use